# git secured by vpn is returning 403 only with my mobile hotspot

Tags: git, vpn

I'm trying to push / pull from a gitlab repository which is secured by a VPN.
I'm connected to my mobile hotspot.
I can access the gitlab repository from the web browser, I can even download the repository as a zip.

When I'm trying to pull, I have a 403 error (I'm not even asked for my credentials).
If I change to my colleague's hotspot, I'm asked for my credentials and everything works fine.

Do someone knows why everything could work using the browser, and not in CLI **only** using my hotspot?

Thanks

Comment: This is your basic "debug the network" problem: find out which IP address you're really connecting to, from the one that works and from the one that doesn't; find out whether you're actually using the VPN, from the one that works and the one that doesn't, etc. Git isn't really involved here: Git just uses https (via libcurl) to connect and then passes authentication off to some credential helper.

Comment: Git has some tracing facilities here but they probably don't run at the right level. You want wireshark or tcpdump.

Comment: I spent some time to debug and found out that it doesn't work with a mobile hotspot because it's using TLS1.3 (it's using TLS1.2 when I'm using standard wifi connection). If anyone knows why it's using 1.3 and not 1.2 and how I can force using 1.2, it can be great. I'm on macOS monterey

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I started to debug using a curl request that fails with my mobile hotspot and doesn't on a standard wifi connection.
I saw that the difference stands in the usage of TLSv1.3 when it fails instead of TLSv1.2 when it works.

I edited my APN settings on my phone (on Android: Settings > Mobile network > Clicked on my SIM > Access point names > Cicked on the APN details) to turn of IPv6 and force IPv4 for APN protocol (and also roaming APN protocol).
After that, it's using TLSv1.2 and I don't receive a 403 anymore.

Hope it can help someone else